# Where should I put a 3.3V Voltage Regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, semiconductors

I've stumbled across lots of schematics and one thing that I find is almost never consistent is where a certain regulator should go. I'm going to be using the LM1117 series. Should the 3.3V regulator go on the output of the 5V regulator, or should it be seperate from the 5V regulator and connect directly to the VCC Input?

Comment: It depends on your design as well, especially on the input voltage and current required from the 3v3 and 5v0 rails. Can you share some more details on the design/project you have in mind?

Comment: It really depends... Does your 5V regulator have enough "overhead" to power the 3.3V side? Is your VCC 6V or 36V? If it is the latter, you need to get rid of 32.7V, which probably will end up as heat (because the LM1117 is a linear regulator).

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov So, I built a module based RF remote with the nrf24l01 and arduino, now I decided to recreate all the modules onto one final PCB. I need the 5v for a status reporting LCD, and the 3.3V for the ATMega328P and nrf24l01. Side Note: This Is Battery Operated by a 12v Lithium Ion battery pack

Comment: What voltage is your "Vcc" and what are the respective current draws?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany this is going to sound bad but after I had the working prototype I let one of my friends try and they broke it before I got a chance to measure anything I have no Vcc or current draw ratings

Comment: Build another, but was it physically broken (dropped etc) or did they let the magic smoke out?

Comment: @SolarMike he dropped it... Into water

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Is Battery Operated by a 12v Lithium Ion battery pack

Using a linear regulator from 12V to 5V would be inefficient (about 60% power lost as heat) so I presume you used a switching regulator. If you don't know how to design one, you can get a canned DC-DC module for a few bucks [from the usual suppliers](https://www.mouser.fr/Power/DC-DC-Converters/_/N-brvxe?P=1yxt7eu&Ns=Pricing%7C0). If the arduino is the only load on your battery, using a 12V to 5V DC-DC instead of a linear regulator will double your battery life, so it is much cheaper than buying a battery with more capacity.

Then, the choice of where to put the 3.3V regulator becomes simple: if it is a linear regulator, then it must be placed after the 5V switcher to exploit the switcher's efficiency. One could also use another 12V to 3V3 switcher, that depends on how much power is used on 3V3.

Where to place it on the board is another question. First, check its dissipation, and make sure it is placed in a spot with enough copper area to act as a heat sink. Heat sinking is done through the TAB pin of the package, which for LM1117 is connected to VOUT, so you will need copper area on VOUT. If you have a ground plane, and the chip dissipates enough to need good heat sinking, it may be beneficial to switch to a LDO which has the tab connected to GND. This makes the heat sinking easier. If you use a thru-hole package, whatever the TAB pin is connected to matters less, but you still need to check if it requires a heat sink or not.

Note LM1117 also has high quiescent current, so if you're going for low power, maybe not the best choice.

Next is noise. In this case it won't matter, but if you want low noise on the output, it is best to have the regulator's GND reference connected close to the GND of the circuit that it powers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on  current draw. For a linear regulator you must be very careful of the power dissipation in the regulator (Vin - Vout)*Iavg, and then look at the thermal dissipation calculations. You really want to minimise this heat, so if your 5V is a switcher and has enough current capacity, it's almost always going to be better to run the 3v3 linear from 5V.

And exception to this might be when you want the 3V3 to be exceptionally free of digital noise (which is likely to leak through from the 5V output) perhaps because you use it to power very sensitive analogue circuitry. Then, running from an unregulated input (at, say 9V) might give a lower noise 3V3 than running it from a relatively dirty 5V.